# Why do not C++ object methods expect a self argument unlike python?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, oop, python-object

After a bit of experimentation I discovered something curious in Python (possibly obvious to experts, forgive me in that case). 
That is, a python class method can be invoked with two different syntax as opposed to C++. I will give two minimum working examples with a simple class which just contains an integer attribute and can add another integer to it. First the C++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class MyClass
{
    int value;
    public:
    MyClass(int arg){value=arg;}
    int add(int arg){return arg+value;}
};

int main()
{
    MyClass anObject(4);
    cout<<"The addition gives "<<anObject.add(6)<<endl;//Outputs 10

    //cout<<"The alternative way to call the method gives "<<MyClass.add(anObject, 6)<<endl;  //Does not work

   //cout<<"Another alternative way to call the method gives "<<MyClass::add(anObject, 6)<<endl;  //Does not work either

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and the python.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, arg=3):self.value=arg
    def add(self, arg):return arg+self.value
anObject=MyClass(4)
print(anObject.add(6)) #The C++ way, Outputs 10
print(MyClass.add(anObject, 6))  #Outputs 10
```

Obviously, this is not a problem that I am trying to solve, but the objective of this question is to see a discussion around why option 2 is made a feature for python while it is not one in C++? Does it follow from some deeper design philosophy of the languages, or something to do with the compiled vs interpreted nature of the languages? Related, why is `self` presented as a dummy argument in python but not in C++?

Comment: Feel free to refer to `value` as `this->value`, instead. You'll be surprised to learn that every class method has something called `this`, which is a pointer, and is logically equivalent to python's `self`.

Comment: isn't it simpler to write `x.add(6)` than `WhatEverXIs.add(x, 6)` ?

Comment: `add(anObject, 6)` -- This looks no different than `C` syntax trying to emulate object-orientedness.  That's a step backwards.

Comment: Take a look at `std::bind` (`https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind`). It may provide something similar... but more complicated

Comment: C++ member functions *are* called with the object (`this`) as the first argument - how else would they know on what object to operate? It's just that the compiler does it for you behind the scenes.

Answer (score 3):

Python classes are runtime objects.  Each object carries with it a `__class__` pointer.

When you do `obj.foo(x)` it looks first locally for a `foo` method; if it fails to find it, it invokes `obj.__class__.foo(obj, x)`.

In C++ classes are not runtime objects.  An object with virtual methods or inheritance has a vtable, but the vtable is not the class, but rather a way to get at minimal & efficient type and dispatching information for methods.

Now you can still invoke a C++ method in a way like a python one:

```
template<class T>
T& as_lvalue(T&&t){return t;}

std::ref( as_lvalue(&MyClass::add) )( anObject, 6 );
```

this uses the INVOKE concept (post [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) you can use it directly with std invoke) and a member function pointer.

This is a library solution.  There is no `MyClass` object in the executable at runtime.

Comment: When I try the std::ref thing I get `use of deleted function ‘void std::ref(const _Tp&&) [with _Tp = int (MyClass::*)(int)]’`

Comment: But, like you said, post c++17 you can do this: `std::invoke(&MyClass::add, anObject, 6)`

Comment: @jerry fixed.  Oops.